# AngularJS Controller function param is undefined when sent from a PHP web page

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have the following problem : 
I'm calling a controller function from a php page as seen below :

```
echo '<div id="bulbsContainer" ng-controller="mainController" data-ng-init="getBulbsData('.$pole_id.')">';
```

Whereas pole_id is a url parameter sent with a GET request to the page retrived with :

```
$pole_id = $_GET["id"];
```

The controller function :

```
$scope.getBulbsData= function(pole_id) {
    alert(pole_id);
    $http.get("http://****/server/load.php?id=" + pole_id)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.poleData = data[0];
        })
}
```

Whenever my ID is comprised from numbers only, like 22 for example, it works good. But, if the ID is P22 for example, the function parameter becomes undefined.

I guess that the problem is that JS has no types, hence P22 is considered a variable and not a value.

I tried using escape quotes to send it as an array : [P22] , or string 'P22' with no success.

The call to the PHP page with the url parameters is made from this line in a directive :

```
<a ng-href="../../*****.php?id={{ info.PoleID }}" style="font-size: 18px;"> Full Data </a>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap your value in quotes.

```
$pole_id = "'".$_GET["id"]."'";
```

Comment: You saved me.. spent some hours trying to wrap anything but this row